# Magic is Software: Why isn't there an overabundance of magical frameworks?

Tags: science-based, computers, balancing-magic-systems

So, magic in this world is basically telling various types of micromachines to do things. In its original state, magic only existed as "sorcery". Sorcery was a flexible and efficient, but incredibly slow language where even simple tasks required months to prepare and execute, as many environmental factors had to be considered.

This changed when Zero, a student of the Witch MIT, invented a "framework", which was essentially a spell, designed to make more spells. More precisely, it took care of the calculation of environmental variables and such, letting Zero create universally workable spells that only needed a few parameters and then would automatically adjust everything else.

Thus, **0Querry/ZeroQuerry** was born. A more rigid set of spells, designed to be beginner-friendly and with the intention of making day-to-day life easier.

Unfortunately, the *Grimoire of ZeroQuerry*, (the user documentation) ended up getting stolen and used by angry script kiddies to wage a war against a kingdom. An overqualified script kiddie, E, noticed that ZeroQuerry had function overloads for several spells which often had an eerily high cost, compared to what they could do.

Having realized that ZeroQuerry was filled with backdoors and after almost getting Zrínyi Miklós-d, E had decided to cut ties with the rest of the script kiddies. She went into hiding where she invented an alternative to ZeroQuerry, **SuicideJS**.

SuicideJS was a combat and team-oriented magical framework that lacked the diverse spell-range of ZeroQuerry, but made up for it with the ability to combine spells via scripts, and tactically advantageous spells such as *Healing Bullet*.

---

Okay that's enough history.

Now, SuicideJS and ZeroQuerry are supposed to be the dominating forces in magic. But that sounds kind of strange. In paper, any human that studies magic should be able to write their own automatization tools for micromachines, given enough time. And why shouldn't they?

- ZeroQuerry is riddled with built-in inefficiencies and its creator maintains the right to shut down any ZeroQuerry magic nearby her.
- SuicideJS is E's closely-guarded secret, only her small group of friends know how to use it and it's rather specialized.

**So, there are many niches in magic that aren't filled and for some reason, nobody wants to fill them. Why?**

---

### Notes

**Micro machines**: Micro machines are organic robots that can be programmed to execute various tasks. They're "naturally" produced by many plants and even animals. Little is known about their origins, but they seem to be a leftover of a much more advanced civilization.

**Tech level of society**: While the political system, architecture, and fashion would suggest late-medieval period; humans have things like advanced firearms and better medical knowledge, courtesy of the mysterious precursor civilization. Swords and similar "primitive" weapons are also often employed, as certain common monsters can render firearms useless through their unique physiology, courtesy of the mysterious precursor civilization.

**Magic** itself is rather powerful, it can give people the power to combat an entire kingdom, but when you add magical defenses, it becomes a rock-paper-scissor scenario where strategizing and information gathering become much more important.

Comment: Basically this is utility fog.

Comment: How can sorcery be "efficient" and "slow" at the same time? (also, you might want to drop one R, unless you're going for wizzard effect)

Comment: For those unaware, This is mostly the premise from the anime, Grimoire of Zero. The magic is generally "borrowed" from someone else's grimoire and Zero kept all the known efficiencies to herself so that her spells will always be quicker and more powerful as well as having killswitches built in to the grimoire version so anyone who didn't make their own spell could be counterspelled at any time.

Comment: Because in stories there's an unstated assumption that 99.9% of unnamed characters are just window-dressing, and don't actually think.  Thus it's plausible that only named characters (and only a small fraction of them) ever come up with any innovations or new strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sunken Cost Fallacy**

If people are trained first in the ZeroQuerry framework and only then introduced to the 'sorcery' roots, then almost everyone would consider it a waste of time to build a new language from scratch - after all, they already have a language that they can use - ZeroQuerry. True, ZeroQuerry isn't useful for certain tasks, but its still faster than building an entirely new framework (for that one specific task), and therefore most people wouldn't even consider building a new language, especially if they've spent years upon years perfecting their use of ZeroQuerry.

Comment: You're essentially describing why people still use Microsoft Windows...

Comment: Sorcery must be nothing like web development then...

Answer (score 0):

> given enough time

You yourself put the kicker in there.  Enough time means a long time that you can't spend on anything else.  And it's going to be substantial, given that sorcery lasted on its own for so long.  (How long?  You don't state how long magic has been loose in the world.  If it's millennia, the difficulty is obvious, but given that it's lasted long enough to have "Witch MIT" obviously it's been at least decades, since colleges do not spring up out of nowhere.)

People don't use magic in order to generate elegant systems, they use it to get stuff done.  Those people who do want to build their own systems tend to be odd and prone to making worse ones (because they don't care, they're just having fun) or ones tailored to their own interest (which are worse ones unless you exactly match their interests).